# Linear combination of step function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, step-function

I am supposed to express the following function as a linear combination of step function: $\left | \varphi  \right |,\varphi ^{3},\varphi -\gamma , max\left \{ \varphi ,\gamma  \right \}$, where:

$$\varphi\left ( x  \right )=\left\{\begin{matrix}
3 & -2\leq x\leq 2 & \\ 
-1 & 0< x< 4  & \\ 
1 & 4\leq x< 5 & 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

$$\gamma\left (  x \right )=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & 0\leq x\leq 1\\ 
1 & 2\leq x\leq 5
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I know, how to draw them separately, but I do not understand, how I am supposed to make the linear combination.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: to make the question less confusing, you should label the functions as $\varphi(x)$ and $\gamma(x)$ instead of $f(\varphi)$ and $f(\gamma)$.

Comment: @SakethMalyala thanks, I edited it

Comment: I'm confused. What is $\phi(1)$? 3? -1?

Comment: @FredBoehm it is this function https://i.imgur.com/39qYDe5.jpg

Comment: Which function would you like to express as a linear combination? Or do you refer to all the function**s** $\left | \varphi  \right |,\varphi ^{3},\varphi -\gamma , max\left \{ \varphi ,\gamma  \right \}$? Which step function do you mean? Or do you mean both function**s** $\varphi(x)$ and $\gamma(x)$?

Comment: @Philipp I refer to all of the function and I mean both functions

Comment: @Emanuel, your question is still not clear because your $\varphi(x)$ is not well defined.